# Recursively Adding Nodes to zss Tree

Tags: python, tree

I want to compare tree distances using the zss module. For that purpose, I am trying to create trees by adding nodes recursively. Unfortunately, the documentation only provides examples in which trees are created with all nodes at once and I can't wrap my head around how to navigate to a child in order to add another node after the tree object was created.

Here is a simple example:

```
from zss import Node
A = (
    Node("f")
        .addkid(Node("a")
            .addkid(Node("h"))
            .addkid(Node("c")))
        .addkid(Node("e"))
    )

B = (
    Node("f")
        .addkid(Node("a")
            .addkid(Node("h"))
            .addkid(Node("c")
                .addkid(Node("l"))))
        .addkid(Node("e"))
    )
```

All I am trying to do now is to add child "l" to node "c" in tree A, such that A == B. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I assume you mean adding "l" to the "c" node in tree A programmatically and not by simply adding it statically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at [`zss`](http://www.github.com/timtadh/zhang-shasha), I see that this might work with the `simple_tree` that it uses:

```
A.get('c').addkid(Node('l'))
```

It seems to use labels that are likely should be unique. So get actually returns the first node with that label found during a depth first search.

```
A.get('f').get('a').get('c').addkid(Node('l'))
```